# TdsInputBufferError not 0 in LoginTimers errors of RING_BUFFER_CONNECTIVITY of sys.dm_os_ring_buffers

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, network

I've got an issue with SQL Server.

The value of `TdsInputBufferError` is not 0 in LoginTimers errors of `RING_BUFFER_CONNECTIVITY` of `sys.dm_os_ring_buffers`.

This happens randomly, once or twice a week, at different times.

Is it an issue with networking drivers ? Virtualization infrastructure? What to monitor to find out? There is no other error/warning log anywhere (windows logs, syslogs, ...).

Full ringbuffer report:

```
<Record id="33" type="RING_BUFFER_CONNECTIVITY" time="614408705">
  <ConnectivityTraceRecord>
    <RecordType>LoginTimers</RecordType>
    <Spid>0</Spid>
    <SniConnectionId>A4478B00-18A1-4147-A65E-2EB505DCA470</SniConnectionId>
    <SniConsumerError>17830</SniConsumerError>
    <SniProvider>7</SniProvider>
    <State>11</State>
    <RemoteHost>xxxx:xxx:xxxx:xx:xxxx:xxx:xxxx:xxxx</RemoteHost>
    <RemotePort>56201</RemotePort>
    <LocalHost>xxxx:xxxx:x:xxxx::xxxx</LocalHost>
    <LocalPort>1433</LocalPort>
    <RecordTime>1/20/2012 10:12:52.32</RecordTime>
    <TdsBuffersInformation>
      <TdsInputBufferError>10054</TdsInputBufferError>
      <TdsOutputBufferError>0</TdsOutputBufferError>
      <TdsInputBufferBytes>0</TdsInputBufferBytes>
    </TdsBuffersInformation>
    <LoginTimers>
      <TotalLoginTimeInMilliseconds>0</TotalLoginTimeInMilliseconds>
      <LoginTaskEnqueuedInMilliseconds>0</LoginTaskEnqueuedInMilliseconds>
      <NetworkWritesInMilliseconds>0</NetworkWritesInMilliseconds>
      <NetworkReadsInMilliseconds>0</NetworkReadsInMilliseconds>
      <SslProcessingInMilliseconds>0</SslProcessingInMilliseconds>
      <SspiProcessingInMilliseconds>0</SspiProcessingInMilliseconds>
      <LoginTriggerAndResourceGovernorProcessingInMilliseconds>0</LoginTriggerAndResourceGovernorProcessingInMilliseconds>
    </LoginTimers>
  </ConnectivityTraceRecord>
  <Stack>
    <frame id="0">0X00000000019EAC4B</frame>
    <frame id="1">0X00000000019E7A36</frame>
    <frame id="2">0X00000000019EC6BE</frame>
    <frame id="3">0X0000000000CA81BC</frame>
    <frame id="4">0X000000000068B888</frame>
    <frame id="5">0X000000000064EF40</frame>
    <frame id="6">0X000000000064ED12</frame>
    <frame id="7">0X000000000064EA17</frame>
    <frame id="8">0X0000000000AB598A</frame>
    <frame id="9">0X0000000000AB5C25</frame>
    <frame id="10">0X0000000000AB5A56</frame>
    <frame id="11">0X0000000000AB61E2</frame>
    <frame id="12">0X0000000074A737D7</frame>
    <frame id="13">0X0000000074A73894</frame>
    <frame id="14">0X0000000076D2652D</frame>
    <frame id="15">0X00000000772CC521</frame>
  </Stack>
</Record>
```

Comment: [Winsock Error 10054](http://geekswithblogs.net/Lance/archive/2007/08/07/Winsock-Error-10054.aspx) is "Connection reset by peer", or "An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host".

Comment: ok so it means something is wrong with the network somewhere.

Comment: Not necessarily. Maybe you can reproduce this error by killing a client mid query. Not sure, haven't tested.

Answer (score 3):

I can't give you answer but I can direct you towards it.

1. You need to download the public symbols for your installed
   version of SQL Server
   http://www.sqlskills.com/BLOGS/PAUL/post/How-to-download-a-sqlservrpdb-symbol-file.aspx
2. You need to able the Trace Flag which shows the public function names for
   that Stack Trace using DBCC TRACEON(3656) with reference to this [blog](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/jonathan_kehayias/archive/2010/12/24/an-xevent-a-day-24-of-31-what-is-the-callstack-Action.aspx)
3. Report the public symbol names for those frames back to us or
   Microsoft CSS (Customer Support Services)

Answer (score 3):

The following .net framework update partially resolved the issue.
See issue 14:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2533523/en-us

@MartinC I'll try your tips asap.
(I still have the problem when database backups are running during the night).