# Where do I find the meaning of TdsInputBufferError numbers?

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, network

We are having some sporadic connection errors on some of our SQL servers. I did some searching and found out about the Ring Buffer in SQL 2008 R2 and found some information, but I am not entirely sure how to figure it out.

Running the query

```
SELECT  CAST(record AS XML)
FROM    sys.dm_os_ring_buffers
WHERE   ring_buffer_type = 'RING_BUFFER_CONNECTIVITY'
```

Gives me some results, on of which is interesting

```
<Record id="4" type="RING_BUFFER_CONNECTIVITY" time="461419385">
  <ConnectivityTraceRecord>
    <RecordType>LoginTimers</RecordType>
    <Spid>0</Spid>
    <SniConnectionId>40A403B2-B860-4877-A1D3-1FA7024356B7</SniConnectionId>
    <SniConsumerError>17830</SniConsumerError>
    <SniProvider>4</SniProvider>
    <State>11</State>
    <RemoteHost>&lt;local machine&gt;</RemoteHost>
    <RemotePort>0</RemotePort>
    <LocalHost />
    <LocalPort>0</LocalPort>
    <RecordTime>5/19/2012 16:29:23.831</RecordTime>
    <TdsBuffersInformation>
      <TdsInputBufferError>109</TdsInputBufferError>
      <TdsOutputBufferError>0</TdsOutputBufferError>
      <TdsInputBufferBytes>0</TdsInputBufferBytes>
    </TdsBuffersInformation>
    <LoginTimers>
      <TotalLoginTimeInMilliseconds>18010</TotalLoginTimeInMilliseconds>
      <LoginTaskEnqueuedInMilliseconds>0</LoginTaskEnqueuedInMilliseconds>
      <NetworkWritesInMilliseconds>0</NetworkWritesInMilliseconds>
      <NetworkReadsInMilliseconds>18010</NetworkReadsInMilliseconds>
      <SslProcessingInMilliseconds>0</SslProcessingInMilliseconds>
      <SspiProcessingInMilliseconds>0</SspiProcessingInMilliseconds>
      <LoginTriggerAndResourceGovernorProcessingInMilliseconds>0</LoginTriggerAndResourceGovernorProcessingInMilliseconds>
    </LoginTimers>
  </ConnectivityTraceRecord>
  <Stack>...</Stack>
</Record>
```

So, my question is, where do I find the meaning for the TDS error numbers. In this case `<TdsInputBufferError>109</TdsInputBufferError>`

Comment: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/109787

Comment: @MartinSmith. Yup, that appears to be what I was looking for. Type it up as an answer and I can mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm not sure that this is an exhaustive list but both Error 109 and Error 10054 (from [this similar question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/11073/3690)) are detailed in the [Database engine errors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/errors-events/database-engine-events-and-errors?view=sql-server-ver15) (*old link: [SQL communication errors](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/109787)*) article.